# No module named cv cv2 No matching distribution found for mediapipe

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, mediapipe

I am using windows

```
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

how to fix it?

I tried

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

```
pip install opencv-python
```

etc etc, still did not work

update: cv2 is fixed, but I am having a problem on mediapipe.
it's showing like this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'E:\python\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

my python version is 3.11.0

Comment: is the location of the packages known to python? With pip the name is `opencv-python`. What error did you receive from pip3?

Comment: yes and It's fixed now. but now I am having a problem in mediapipe, it's showing like this........ ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'E:\python\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: usually you should install program always in the same way, not mixing with (don't know with Windows) package manager and pip). I usually do everything with `python -m pip install xyz` and never had any problems (also with opencv). What happen when you follow the advise in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the install of cv2 goes nicer with system install: `apt install python3-opencv`

Answer (score 0):

I think, with `Python 3.11.0` we can't install `mediapipe`. What I suggest you is to try lowering your Python version to `3.7.0` and install `mediapipe`. If you face the same issue then try installing `mediapipe==0.8.9`